# En el seguimiento de medallas no se muestran todas las etiquetas en las que participo

Tags: soporte, perfil, medallas, medallas-de-etiqueta

Quiero hacer el seguimiento de siguiente medalla de mi etiqueta principal, [google-apps-script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), pero esta no se muestra en el diálogo de selección de etiqueta a seguir, me parece que se trata de un bug.

Etiquetas en perfil:

[image: ejemplo de etiquetas en perfil]

Seguimiento de etiquetas:

[image: ejemplo de seguimiento de etiquetas]

Nótese que en el recorte mostrado arriba no se incluyen ni [google-apps-script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) ni [google-hoja-de-calculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-calculo), ambas etiquetas con bajo  número de preguntas comparado con [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) que es la segunda etiqueta con mayor número de preguntas. Asumo que se debe a un bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no se trata de un bug: para optar a ganar una medalla de una etiqueta, esa etiqueta debe tener al menos 100 preguntas.

Sin embargo, ahora mismo [google-apps-script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) tiene solamente 34.

De [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/209901), esto es, *¿Qué son las etiquetas de medalla? ¿Cómo funcionan?*:

> #### ¿En qué etiquetas se pueden conseguir medallas?
>
> Una etiqueta debe aparecer en al menos 100 preguntas para ser tenida en cuenta para las medallas de etiqueta.

En consecuencia, la aplicación de seguimiento de medallas incorpora esta funcionalidad y solamente muestra aquellas para las que se podría conseguir la medalla.